# Color matching library

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm looking for a way to get a matching color(s) for any given color.

Is there a way to do this either programmatically or using a library (in Java/Android)?

Thanks!

(As in a color that goes well with said color, This is a good example: [colorcombos.com/colors/FF0000](http://colorcombos.com/colors/FF0000))

Comment: What I found is that if you use hexadecimals : try doing FFFFFF - currentColorValue = complementaryColor ... Example with FFFFFF - Red (ff0000) = Cyan (00FFFF) which is a complementary color

Comment: I don't know if it's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Seems like a good method, though my use of "Complementary" might be wrong since complementary apparently is the polar opposite, and i'm looking for colors that match regardless of being opposites

Comment: Do complementary colors always match and look good together?

Comment: I think so, at least that's what I found :)

Comment: Try that on gray: `808080` -> `7f7f7f`. Not exactly complementary, huh.

Comment: @Andreas in most cases the result is not that bad but I agree with you. It is because they represent the middle of the scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method for getting the most contrasting color, would be to bounce each RGB color as far as possible. By this I mean a value of 00-7F becomes FF, and a value of 80-FF becomes 00. The result will always be saturated.

If you want the complimentary color to stay consistent with the original color, e.g a pastel red becomes a pastel cyan, things get more complicated, but it all depends on the color model you use, e.g. RGB vs HSV vs others.

You could use the formula of `0xFF - value` for each RGB color, but a gray will stay gray, so that's not always good.

---

As for how to work with the RGB color values, here's how to find most contrasting color of a color given as the hex string.

```
String color = "2E8B57" // SeaGreen
int r1 = Integer.parseInt(color.substring(0, 2), 16);
int g1 = Integer.parseInt(color.substring(2, 2), 16);
int b1 = Integer.parseInt(color.substring(4, 2), 16);
int r2 = (r1 < 0x80 ? 0xFF : 0x00);
int g2 = (g1 < 0x80 ? 0xFF : 0x00);
int b2 = (b1 < 0x80 ? 0xFF : 0x00);
String newColor = String.format("%02x%02x%02x", r2, g2, b2);
// newColor = "FF00FF" (Fuchsia)
```

Using the other way, you'd use:

```
int r2 = 0xFF - r1;
int g2 = 0xFF - g1;
int b2 = 0xFF - b1;
String newColor = String.format("%02x%02x%02x", r2, g2, b2);
// newColor = "D174A8" (Hopbush)
```

*Color names are from [`www.htmlcsscolor.com`](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com): [SeaGreen](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/2E8B57), [Fuchsia](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/FF00FF), [Hopbush](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/D174A8)*

Comment: After a quick research, the second method still seems to be the more reasonable because gray has no complementary color so it is complementary to every other color of the scope because it represents the mix between every color with it's complementary. http://www.ask.com/science/complementary-color-gray-12f5ef6e4d66e69e

Comment: @YassinHH It depends on the purpose of the "matching" color. If the given color is a foreground color, and you need a matching background color, then the contrasting color is more appropriate.

Comment: It all depends on the design techniques used indeed. Let's leave that to UX Pro's :)